# Drawing a square with Matlab's 'line' command

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot a square on Matlab, specifically using the `line` command, with corners at the points (0,0), (0, rho), (rho, 0) and (rho, rho)

```
% create axes
x = linspace(0,10,100);
y = linspace(0,20,100);
rho = 2*pi;
% plot
figure;
A = line([0 0],[0 rho]);
B = line([0 0],[rho 0]);
C = line([0 rho],[rho rho]);
D = line([rho 0],[rho rho]);
fill(A,B,C,D,'b');
```

However, line `D` fails to appear in my figure and moreover, the `fill` command is not working, although that part is really quite optional. My main issue is why the aforementioned line won't appear in the plot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you aren't specifying the coordinates for the box properly.  Remember that `line` takes in two vectors where the first vector is a list of `x` coordinates and the second vector is a list of `y` coordinates.  Each i<sup>th</sup> pair of `(x, y)` will have a line drawn from its previous (i-1)<sup>th</sup> point up to the i<sup>th</sup> point except for the first point of course.  The lines drawn by `A` and `B` are the **same** line.  The same can be said with `C` and `D`.  It's just a matter of modifying the statements so you're drawing the line correctly.

Drawing the box in lovely ASCII graphics for illustration:

```
(0, rho)      (rho, rho)
------------------------
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
------------------------
(0, 0)           (rho, 0)
```

You need to draw four lines.  Let's traverse counter-clockwise:

1. Going from `(0, 0)` to `(0, rho)`
2. Going from `(0, rho)` to `(rho, rho)`
3. Going from `(rho, rho)` to `(rho, 0)`
4. Going from `(rho, 0)` to `(0, 0)`

Therefore, modify your code to be:

```
rho = 2*pi;
A = line([0 0],[0 rho]);
B = line([0 rho],[rho rho]);
C = line([rho rho],[rho 0]);
D = line([rho 0],[0 0]);
```

BTW, the code above may not be portable for later.  You are going to get line handles which is fine by you don't use this as an input into `fill`.

We finally get:

[image]

It may be cleaner to just put all of the coordinates in just two vectors and call `line`.  This will also make this play nicely with `fill`:

```
rho = 2*pi;
x = [0,   0, rho rho, 0];
y = [0, rho, rho,  0, 0];
line(x, y);
hold on;
fill(x, y, 'b');
```

Notice that we use the proper convention for `line`, then draw it, then we fill it.  If you follow the logic specified earlier, we draw a line from `(0, 0)` to `(0, rho)`, then from `(0, rho)` to `(rho, rho)`, then from `(rho, rho)` to `(rho, 0)` then finally from `(rho, 0)` back to `(0, 0)`.  Notice that we had to use the origin `(0, 0)` at the beginning and at the end to ensure that we draw the line at the bottom edge of the square.  We also use `hold on` to add the filled box in after the square boundary that you've drawn on the figure.  `fill` takes in a vector of coordinates just like `line` does.  We get:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have made a number of mistakes regarding the input arguments for [`line`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) and [`fill`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html). Firstly, the inputs to `line` are the x coordinates for the line points followed by the y coordinates for the line points, **NOT** successive pairs of `(x,y)` points. The following will plot your square correctly, starting at `(0,0)` and drawing lines clockwise:

```
A = line([0 0], [0 rho]);      % Left edge
B = line([0 rho], [rho rho]);  % Top edge
C = line([rho rho], [rho 0]);  % Right edge
D = line([rho 0], [0 0]);      % Bottom edge
```

The values returned are [handles to the line graphics objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html). These can be used to modify the line properties, but you can't pass these to `fill`. You should instead pass polygon vertex data.

There is an easier way to handle all of this, though. You can instead define a vector of x and y coordinates for the vertices of your square, making it much easier to plot lines and filled polygons:

```
X = [0 0 rho rho 0];
Y = [0 rho rho 0 0];
hLine = line(X, Y);
hold on;  % Needed to add to existing plot instead of erasing
fill(X, Y, 'b');
```